# Подсчёт длины блока в символах(ch) css

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Вопрос заключается в следующем: нужно в width передать значение в ch для разных текcтовых блоков по средствам css и html, для того чтобы можно было применить один стиль для разных по длинне текстовых блоков  Я конечно понимаю что это не языки программирования но всё же...

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
width: 5ch;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: red;
animation: printed-text 2s steps(21);
}

@keyframes printed-text{
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="text">lorem</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="text">loremlorem</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".text").each(function(){
 $(this).css("width",$(this).text().length+"ch");
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
width:5ch;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: red;
animation: printed-text 2s steps(21);
}

@keyframes printed-text{
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="text">lorem</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="text">loremlorem</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
:root {
  --t: 1ch;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
width: var(--t);
overflow: hidden;
background-color: red;
animation: printed-text 2s steps(21);
}

@keyframes printed-text{
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="text" style="--t:5ch">lorem</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="text" style="--t:10ch">loremlorem</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Решение хорошее, но в safari не работает.